# Does AdminUpdateUserAttributes create new user in Cognito UserPool?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

### Summary

AdminUpdateUserAttributes creates new user in Cognito UserPool when I try to change email and email_verified.
I would like to update 'email' attribute without verify email.

### Code

```js
const provider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
provider.adminUpdateUserAttributes({
        UserPoolId: userPoolId,
        Username: username, // this is previous email
        UserAttributes: [
          {
            Name: "email",
            Value: email, // this is new email
          },
          {
            Name: "email_verified",
            Value: "true"
          }
        ]
      }, ...)
```

### Question

Email is set as username alias.

I want to update user's email by adminUpdateUserAttributes.
Sometimes successfully user updated.
However, I realized some user duplicated when email updated.
They have all the same attribute values except email and username(UUID).

Why is this situation happened? and How to solve it?

#### UPDATE

The whole code I tried below.

```js
const provider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

  provider.adminGetUser({
    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
    Username: username // previous email
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack)
    }else {
      const oldUsername = data.Username // get uuid username
      provider.adminUpdateUserAttributes({
        UserPoolId: userPoolId,
        Username: oldUsername,
        UserAttributes: [
          {
            Name: "email",
            Value: email, // new email
          },
          {
            Name: "email_verified",
            Value: "true"
          }
        ]
      }, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
          }else {
            provider.adminGetUser({
              UserPoolId: userPoolId,
              Username: email, // new email
            }, function(err, data) {
              if (err){
                console.log(err, err.stack)
              }else{
                console.log(data.Username, oldUsername)
                if (data.Username !== oldUsername){ // I would like to disable old user if they are duplicated.
                  provider.adminDisableUser({
                    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
                    Username: oldUsername
                  }, callback)
                }
              }
            })
          }
      })
    }
  })
```

Sorry about nested ugly code.

#### Idea

This code checks UUID usernames are different or not.
If UUIDs are different, I thought it means user was duplicated.
I try to disable user when that happen.

#### Real

Even though UUIDs are the same, new user is created.

It seems that the function, AdminUpdateUserAttributes is not always to create new user. So I cannot disable user every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. When you update the email, which acts as the unique identifier of the user in your case, it will create a new user. The old user will be disabled. You can add some further code to delete this old user if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So why is it sometimes update user correctly? There are some cases to update email without changing username(uuid). And the old user was not disabled. It was still enabled after create duplicated user.